Import a text file to Excel using VBA on the same sheet
I want to import a text file into the current Excel Sheet.
Code I found keeps the text as I want, however it opens a new Excel workbook and pastes it there. This isn't ideal since at times I'll have to loop through many of these, and I have VBA/macros running on the tabs on which I'd like these to import. Any references to Sheets, ActiveSheet, etc., do not work with Workbooks, but rather the Workbook object, so I simply cannot manually reference the sheet I want.
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\textexample.txt", _
  Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
  Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
  Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
  Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), _
  Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1)), _
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Power Query does import everything into my desired sheet with proper delimiters. It adds it into a table, with drop downs, formatting, etc. I want it in plain text, just as it would be in a .txt document. The only idea I have is to paste the table far away from my data, then have VBA copy the text values into where I want it, then delete the table. This also cannot be the only solution.
My version of Excel does not have the Legacy Text option to simply do it with regular text and everything.
Is there a way to import data from a text file into a sheet directly, no styles, tables or formatting?

A ListObject can be converted to a regular Range using the UnList method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.unlist

This will convert it to a Range but keep the colors/formatting.  While I can add a few lines of VBA do get rid of this, it still opens the table/data on a new Sheet.  I'd like it on the current sheet in which I'm working.  It is a solution though if I am okay with deleting the tabs and coding the unformatting...


OpenText open the text file in a new window, but you can copy the sheet to your workbook and close it.

Sub Demo()
    Dim curWK As Workbook
    Set curWK = ActiveWorkbook ' or ThisWorkbook
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\textexample.txt", _
        Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
          Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
          Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), _
          Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Sheets(1).Copy after:=curWK.Sheets(curWK.Sheets.Count)
        .Close
    End With
    ' Your code to process the imported data
End Sub



Use QueryTable to import text file

Option Explicit
Sub QueryTablesSample()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim oQt As QueryTable
    Dim fileName As String
    ' Specify the file path of the text file
    fileName = "d:\temp\data.csv"
    ' Specify the worksheet where you want to import the data
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' Clear existing data (optional)
    oSht.Cells.Clear
    ' Add a QueryTable to the worksheet
    Set oQt = oSht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fileName, Destination:=oSht.Range("A1"))
    ' Specify properties of the QueryTable
    With oQt
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited ' Specify the file parse type (e.g., xlDelimited, xlFixedWidth)
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True ' Specify delimiter (e.g., comma, tab, semicolon)
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1) ' Specify column data types (e.g., xlGeneralFormat)
        .Refresh ' Refresh the QueryTable to import data
    End With
    ' Clean up
    Set oQt = Nothing
    Set oSht = Nothing
End Sub



How to access From Text(legacy)?


File > Option > From Text(legacy)



Your first solution still opens a new workbook.  At times I may have to cycle through 50+ text files, so having them open and close new workbooks seems rather messy and intensive.  I'm not able to test your second method, but it looks like what I was doing originally with the Query Tables where I am getting the table formatting I don't desire.  Is the From Text option you are showing me how to upload the data in just a text format (to display similar to what you showed)?

Ok I went ahead and tested it real quick...checking the "From Text (Legacy)" did nothing...it still imports all my plain text data as a table with the drop downs, formatting, color scheme, etc.

but it looks like what I was doing originally with the Query Tables where I am getting the table formatting I don't desire - No. You can see the output on the 1st screenshot.

checking the "From Text (Legacy)" did nothing will add Legacy Wizards on Excel Ribbon. it still imports all my plain text data as a table with the drop downs, formatting, color scheme, etc. I don't think so. I've tested it on M365.
